# Converting android date time into mysql datetime

Tags: android, mysql

Is there any way I can get datetime format like '`YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`' to be stored as datetime format in mysql from android date of format '`MM-DD-YY`' and time of format '`HH:MM`'

**Input :** android date '`MM-DD-YY`' and android time '`HH:MM`'
**Output:** mysql datetime '`YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`'

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to parse and format the dates :

```
// Parse the input date
SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm");
Date inputDate = fmt.parse("10-22-2011 01:00");

// Create the MySQL datetime string
fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String dateString = fmt.format(inputDate);
```

Comment: i tried SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
          String dateString = fmt.format("10-22-2011 01:00");  it gives illegal argument exception

Answer (score 0):

I find it much easier to store dates as ints in the database e.g. `long millis - date.getTime()`. Then when you want to display it you can convert it back to a date and add whatever formatting suits your required output.

Comment: It's easier, but what if you want to use mysql functions like DAY(), MONTH(), ... ?

Comment: That's a very bad idea. In fact it's a question to stack overflow, that usually starts I have this int and I wnat to do something date ish to it in my database...

Comment: What's so bad about it? Store it as a string and you've comitted it to a format but as an int you can format it how you want or need.

Comment: nice idea John...Specially if you are only going to store and retrieve dates from database,this would be the best option