# How to save date type value in datetime field of a table in sqlite

Tags: android

I am using editText input type is date and i want that user will enter date in date format and store it in a datetime field of a table in sqlite. Is this possible? Because the editText date format is dd/mm/yyyy and in sqlite it is yyyy/mm/dd.

I have designed one form on which there is a edit text by which user will enter a date and i want to store this date in sqlite whose field's type is datetime.How to do it? I am new to android so if anybody know the solution please provide me the answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8194282/converting-android-date-time-into-mysql-datetime?rq=1

Comment: save the datetime as varchar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my issue:

1. I have taken Datatype of date is datetime in sqlite3 .
2. I have used textview,datepicker and a button in date_picker_demo.xml saved in layout.
3. DatePicker.java

   ```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           db = new DatabaseHelper(this);
           date_textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_date);
           picker_date = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datepicker1);
           button_create = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_create);
   }

   @Override 
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
       date = new Date(picker_date.getYear()-1900, picker_date.getMonth(), picker_date.getDayOfMonth()); 
           sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

          //sdf.format()->converting date to string
   String sdate = sdf.format(date); 

         //inserting date into database
            try {
       db.createDataBase();
   } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   db.openDataBase();
   Cursor cur = db.select();

   for(cur.moveToFirst(); !cur.isAfterLast(); cur.moveToNext()){
       if(cur.isLast()){
           s_id = Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(0));
           s_id = s_id + 1;
       }
   }
            db.insertDate(s_id,sdate);
      }
   ```
4. DatabaseHelper.java

   ```
    public Cursor select(){
    String qry = "Select subscription_id from Subscription_Master";
    cur = sqdb.rawQuery(qry,null); 
   return cur;
    }

    public void insertDate(int s_id,String s_date){

   String query = "insert into Subscription_TAB(subscription_id,start_date) values("+s_id+",date('"+s_date+"'))";
    sqdb.execSQL(query);
    Log.d("value","inserted");
    }
   ```

Date is inserted in database successfully.